# How to output dynamic arrays values form container array in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, return, singly-linked-list, return-by-value

I will try to explain my situation a first.
I have a class with structure inside of it and an array of this container calss

```
class A
{
    struct B
    {
        int I;
        B *next;
    };

    B *objOfB; //Array of structures
    B *lastB;  //Pointer to last objOfB element

public:
    //Method for adding values to objOfB
    void addB(int i)
    {
        B *temp = new B;
        temp->I = i;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(ing == NULL)
        {
            last = temp;
            objOfB = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = temp;
            last = temp;
        }
    }
};
```

Object's array is used in some functions file

```
A * objA = A[100];
```

What I can not figure out is how to hand single value of `objOfB`. There is a simple example which will go from start to end of `objOfB`.

```
for (B *temp = objOfB; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
  cout << temp->I << endl;
}
```

I would like to execute this loop in functions file but I can not think of method which would not return all `objOfB` (it is used in the first part of the loop `B *temp = objOfB;`).
Here are the methods I have created to execute this loop:

```
B listOfBs() { return *objOfB;  }
B toNextB() { return *objOfB->next; }
bool noLastB(){ return objOfB->next != NULL; }
```

And how it works it may be used in the loop:

```
for (B *temp = listOfBs(); noLastB(); temp = toNextB()) {
  cout << temp->I << endl;
}
```

However I understand that all 3 methods are not suitable for this loop. So I need some method to return value and another one to tell that the next value should be read...
Hope not it is clearer what I am trying to achieve.

**How to pass container class dynamic arrays of structures value using a method?**

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have the class `A` (that represents a wrapper of singly-linked list) and this simple `struct B` nested in it :

```
struct B
{
    int I;
    B *next;
};
```

and you want the class `A` to also provide an interface, that would provide the simpler way of iterating through this list.

At first, this data member is very confusing:

```
B *objOfB; //Array of structures
```

since you are treating it as a pointer to the first element. Good start would be to rename it to: `B *head;` So now each instance of `B` can point to the `next` element and you have the pointer to the `head`, last element is the element with `next` equal to `NULL`, you don't need `B *lastB;`.

Then you will realize that methods you tried to provide don't make much sense:

```
B listOfBs() { return *head;  }
B toNextB() { return *head->next; }
bool noLastB(){ return head->next != NULL; }
```

there is no reason why these methods should return by value and since the definition of `struct B` will have to be visible to the caller anyway. For the sake of [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), just make `head` the public data member of `A` and rename `A` to more meaningful name, for example `MyList`. Then let the caller do this:

```
MyList list;
...
for (B* b = list.head; b != NULL; b = b->next) {
    ...
}
```